# Overlay Transparency should override Parent Background

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay, transparency, clip

I have a Overlay over my WPF Applicaiton, it shows some boarders as "context sensitive help". The boarders should now overrule the parent background and show the content behind (some kind of a view Port through the background).

The Controls look like this without Overlay:

[image: Overlay Inactive]

With the Overlay Activated it looks like this:

[image: Overlay Active]

The Overlay is a Usercontrol containing a ListBox of Items it should supply a boarder to.
The ListBoxPanel is a Canvas and the ListBoxItems are the Boarders(Buttons) you can see, which are moved over the UIElements they should surround using a ItemContainerStyle.

The Overlay looks like this:

```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding HelpItems}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" IsTabStop="True"
                  helpers:FocusHelper.FocusOnLoad="True" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource EmptyFocusVisual}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Button Command="{Binding ShowPopupCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="{Binding Width}" />
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="{Binding Height}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I want the overlay to be transparent inside the boarder, while keeping the semitransparent dimming background on the list box, in other words the empty space of my ListBox should be Gray.
Is there any easy way I can get the Light Blue border to show the Content behind the panel without the semi transparent background of my Overlay?

This is the target result:

[image: Expected]

I did as well try to create a Opacity filter but it is the wrong way around. And it does not seem there is a easy way to invert a opacity filter.

Comment: Are those borders bitmap effects? how are they being rendered?

Comment: No the borders are ListBoxItems (a button with a custom style)The whole Overlay is just a ListBox with Canvas as ItemPanel moving these "Borders" over the Actual controls

Comment: Ok, sorry if i'm being tedious but i want to get this straight. you want the buttons and textboxes rendered *over* the overlay right?
Also, could we see the Xaml that makes up this dialog? it'd make answering this question a lot easier.

Comment: no i want the overlay to be transparent inside the boarder, while keeping the semitransparent dimming background on the listbox, in other words the empty space of my ListBox should be Gray.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just change the background of the listbox then?

Comment: Why dont you add the overlay in the listbox, over the items panel but under the items?

Comment: If Emmanuel's solution doesn't work for you, you can probably accomplish this by setting the fill of the borders to be a VisualBrush bound to the underlying content, and then allow input to pass through to the controls below. I'm putting this as a comment rather than an answer since I'm not set up to write sample code that would demonstrate this, but I think that should work with what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console,

Ok we have "to make some holes in the ice".

So here is a custom control : `OverlayWithGaps` that draws itself, with a given background that can be semi transparent.

`OverlayWithGaps` has a Rect Collection that represents the gaps :

```
    public ObservableCollection<Rect> Gaps
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Rect>)GetValue(GapsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GapsProperty, value); }
    }
    private static FrameworkPropertyMetadata fpm = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        null,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
        null,
        null
    );
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GapsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Gaps", typeof(ObservableCollection<Rect>), typeof(OverlayWithGaps), fpm);
```

With `AffectsRender`, if that dependency property changes redrawing will happen.

Here is the drawing function :

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
{
    if (Gaps != null && Gaps.Count > 0)
    {
        Geometry newGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
        foreach (var gap in Gaps)
            // remove each rectangle  of the global clipping rectangle :
            // we make "a hole in the ice"
            newGeometry = Geometry.Combine(newGeometry, 
                new RectangleGeometry(gap), 
                GeometryCombineMode.Exclude, 
                transform: null);
        // When the geometry is finished, we make the hole
        dc.PushClip(newGeometry);
    }
    dc.DrawRectangle(Background, null, new Rect(0, 0, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
}
```

**EDIT**
3. Rectangles are provided from the ItemsControl ListViewItems

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // overlay is the OverlayWithGaps instance   
    // in the window
    overlay.Gaps = new ObservableCollection<Rect>(
        itemsControl1.FindAllVisualDescendants()
            .OfType<Grid>()
            .Select(grid => {
                Point relativePoint = grid.TransformToAncestor(this)
                    .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                return new Rect(relativePoint.X, 
                    relativePoint.Y, 
                    grid.ActualWidth, 
                    grid.ActualHeight
                );
            })
    );
}
```

Note that I select Grids in the LINQ query, because they are in the DataTemplate.
But the Linq query could select nearly anything (by name, ...)

The `FindAllVisualDescendants()` extension function can be found here :
 [Datagrid templatecolumn update source trigger explicit only updates first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736265/datagrid-templatecolumn-update-source-trigger-explicit-only-updates-first-row/32741477#32741477)

4. Here is the full working solution : http://1drv.ms/1OO2gWk

Best coding

Comment: @Console, an option to my solution is create a a dependency property in the OverlayWithGaps class. That property would be an ItemsControl. So the code of finding the Rects would be better encapsulated. But that would couple OverlayWithGaps to work only with ItemsControl. Regarding your level of coding I saw in your code, I think it would not be difficult for you Console. But don't hesitate to tell me if anything is missing or unclear.